# Keep parallax from going backward

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

Hi all I am working on this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/arobichaux/Qbrv9/29/ and I basically am having a few problems.

Firsly, I want it to not be able to go past the beginning of the photo (no scrolling to past left:0px;) and also I am wondering what is a good way to make sure that the length of the mouse movement in the live area will take them ALL THE WAY to the end of the image? The image is 5464px wide.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
var strength1 = 1000;
var strength2 = 2000;
var strength3 = 5000;
$("html").mousemove(function(e){
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 15);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 1);
    var newvalueX = 2* pageX * -1;
    var newvalueY = 1* pageY * -1;
  $('#background').css("background-position", (strength1 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1)+"px "+(strength1  / $(window).height() * pageY * -1)+"px");
    $('#middleground').css("background-position", (strength2 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1)+"px "+(1  / $(window).height() * pageY * -1)+"px");
    $('#foreground').css("background-position", (strength3 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1)+"px "+(1 / $(window).height() * pageY * -1)+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qbrv9/30/)**

First off, very nice question for a first time user. The fiddle is well presented, and I think that parallax is becoming more popular and relevant by the hour.

There are two issues that I will address, and in my opinion they are minor (your code works rather well - good job).

**no scrolling to past left:0px;**

This is easy, just change the check for `pageX` after it is calculated, and if it is less than 0, set it to 0. Pretty straight forward collision detection.

```
var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 15);
if( pageX < 0 ) pageX = 0;
```

**take them ALL THE WAY to the end of the image**

This issue arises from the fact that you set the width of the area to less than the image width. Notably, your fiddle lists `strength3 = 5000` whereas it should be

```
var strength3 = 5464;
```

Comment: Thanks this was of great help and I was able to get it how I wanted...had to take some time to re-animate it etc...but now I am having some actual trouble implementing onto JOOMLA from JS Fiddle. I have found how to call JSQuery but when I load the page the two divs only display above one another and never overlap as they do in the JSFIDDLE.

I had to leave out the <code> div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}</code>

Comment: i got it to work but for some reason when i try and put on JOOMLA i have to take out the <div> code from the CSS window otherwise it makes my template all cray...and when i do that the two images no longer ever overlap ...even if i define with absolute, 0px left and 0px top...any ideas why this may be? if you go to groovefootwear.com and click on the TESTER link...you will see what I mean...Do you have any ideas for me, really stuck on this! THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @user2162042 - That is probably because in the fiddle there are only those 3 divs, and in your main site, there are many divs. You should give your 3 divs a unique class name, and then use that class name to reference in the style. See this demo for using a class name for those 3: http://jsfiddle.net/Qbrv9/43/

Comment: ah thank you! just made the change and put it online..fixed the problem except now the bottom menu bar (pink) is dissapeared? I think it may be covered by the display so I tried to add a css element called 3dspacer with a height of 600 to at least push it down but didnt work...do you know why that is??

Comment: it seems that on all the other pages, the joomla articles push that bottom bar down, but for some reason this one doesnt?